# Where to set Intune policy to Mandatory

Tags: windows, group-policy, microsoft-edge, intune

I created two Microsoft Intune policies to set the homepages for end-users' Edge browser: `RestoreOnStartup` and `RestoreOnStartupURLs`. This works for computers that join Intune after I deployed the policy, but not for existing computers that are already joined. (I want to force the change once and then change it to Recommended, to let people change it thereafter.)

Per Microsoft's documentation on these policies:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#restoreonstartupurls

both can be made Mandatory, but where does one set that?

Comment: Have you done [Group Policy Update](https://lazyadmin.nl/it/gpupdate-force-command/)?

Comment: [You can set mandatory or recommended policies to configure Microsoft Edge with the Group Policy Editor for both Active Directory and individual computers. You can scope policy settings to either the Computer Configuration or User Configuration by selecting the appropriate node as described below.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/configure-microsoft-edge).  For an answer we will need more information on what you have already done.

Comment: It seems I don't need to do a gpupdate because the policy does push out to the computers. Also, it gpupdate relevant with Intune? (I don't have AD or AD hybrid, only AzureAD.)

Comment: Hi @Ramhound, this sounds like something that only works with AD or AD Hybrid. I don't have on-prem AD, only AzureAD and Intune. Is there somewhere in Intune (Endpoint Manager) that lets me change this policy setting?